# Cant load module threejs

Tags: javascript, npm, three.js, webgl

I am fairly new to threejs.
Until now I have only worked on projects using a dev server (vite) locally. Thus, I could only access my projects from the browser on my computer.
This is how I include my files for this project:

```
<body>
    <script type="module" src="node_modules/three/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="myapp.js"></script>
</body>
```

This works totally fine with the vite server locally after running *npm run dev*. However, I would like to serve my project on the network with a python server, so it can be opened in a browser on a different device:

*python -m http.server --bind 172.16.0.0 9999*

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. Here are the errors Firefox is showing:

```
Loading failed for the module with source “http://172.16.0.0:9999/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls”. 172.16.0.0:9999:12:1
Loading module from “http://172.16.0.0:9999/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
172.16.0.0:9999
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “three”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

Here's how I import OrbitControls in myapp.js:

```
import {OrbitControls} from "./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"
```

That's the only import statement I have in myapp.js

I would appreciate any help, thanks !

Comment: `vite build` and serve the output

Comment: `vite build` only outputs _Unknown command: vite_. It might be important that I note, I created the vite app by using the command `npm init @vitejs/app`. I don't have a vite executable

Comment: You probably have a script called `build` that do `vite build` in `package.json`. if not  add it.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski
`npm run build`
outputs:
`> stylized_planet_project@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v3.1.6 building for production...
✓ 9 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                 0.33 KiB
dist/assets/index.e73621f3.js   691.46 KiB / gzip: 181.73 KiB

(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 KiB after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputmanualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.`

Comment: This is fine, just a warning

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Ok, so then I went into the _dist_ folder created by build. It holds an _index.html_ file and an _assets_ folder containing a single Javascript file. When I run the python server in that _dist_ folder and try to open the link in my browser, I still get an error and can't see my project: `Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined     <anonymous> http://172.16.0.0:9999/assets/index.c246ad9c.js:3112     <anonymous> http://172.16.0.0:9999/assets/index.c246ad9c.js:3117`

Comment: Why don't you just import THREE.js and the other scripts the usual way from your myapp.js file?

Comment: @zoran404 I have changed it now. Here are the imports in the Javscript file: `import * as THREE from "three";
import {GLTFLoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls" ;`. I don't import anything from the HTML file anymore. Now, when I try to access the python server from my web browser, I get an error that the gltf models I import can't be found. I load them with the GLTFLoader.load("name_of_my_gltf_file") function.

Answer (score 0):

This error message pops up non-stop... I finally found a vanilla-js way (not via npm installs) to include three to develop the site locally. Then I upload it and tattaaaa it appears once again for all modules:
Loading module from “mydomain.xy/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Everytime I try to implement three.js in whatever way,it fails.... There's one way so far on youtube where the implementation is even as neat as that code completion works. No other non-npm implementation but the one on their website works. And the one on the website cannot even be put into a separate file, no the error pops up again if you do so. And as said, after uploading it onto the webserver it fails again. Unbelievable.. This library is so amazing, would be great if it was working more times than it doesn't.

At least for me the following was working locally (as said not yet on server):
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation
Goto "installation from cdn", maybe that helps you.. I don't like this node stuff very much, but there's one single good implementation video out there if you do it via nodejs/npm:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJAfLdUgdc4&list=PLjcjAqAnHd1EIxV4FSZIiJZvsdrBc1Xho
With that tutorial everything was working for me, even auto completion which is rare so far on my end, but it got to tiresome after a while having a hundred folder for static and whatnot content, ya, I'm new to things like parcel, webpack etc and not yet a fan^^